# How can I customize Sqoop Import serialization from Mysql to HBase?

Tags: mysql, serialization, import, hbase, sqoop

Currently, I have a MySql table "email_history" as below.

```
email_address          updated_date    modification
janet.ford@mmch.org    2014-10-20      NEW:confidence::75|NEW:sources::cif
r.wagland@soton.ac.uk  2014-10-20      NEW:confidence::75|NEW:sources::cif|NEW:user::r.wagland
```

The field "email_address" and "modification" are VARCHAR and "updated_date" is DATE.

When importing to HBase, the row key needs to be email_address concatenating byte array presented date. And the value needs to be the modification, but the ':' needs to be converted to byte 0x1F and '|' needs to be converted to byte 0x1E. the following is an example of this format.

```
janet.ford@mmch.org\x00\x00\x01KS,\x7F\x00        column=c:v, timestamp=1423082506912, value=new\x1Fconfidence\x1F75\x1Enew\x1Fsources\x1Fcif
```

By default, Sqoop serializes all values to HBase by converting each field to its string representation, and then inserts the UTF-8 bytes of this string in the target cell.

But there is no way for string to represent a character like 0x1E, thus the default serialization cannot meet my desire. Can anybody tell me how to customize the serialization and convert the content in the mysql table to the desired bytes format and thus put into HBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent 0x1E (up arrow) with CHAR(30) and 0x1F (down arrow) with CHAR(31), therefore, you can provide a free query and perform the replacements. This should achieve exactly what you're looking for:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/[db] \
--username [user] --password [pwd] \
--query 'SELECT CONCAT(email_address,updated_date) as id, REPLACE(REPLACE(modification,":",CHAR(31),uri),"|",CHAR(30),uri) as value FROM email_history WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--split-by id \
--hbase-create-table --hbase-table [your_hbase_table] \
--hbase-row-key id --column-family [your_hbase_column_family]
```

Just replace the code in brackets accordingly and leave `$CONDITIONS` as is (it's required)

About storing the date part of the composite row key as a byte[] I supposse you want to store it as a 4 byte int (a posix timestamp) o something like that... Sadly, you can't: everything will be imported into HBase as a byte encoded UTF8 string, but it shouldn't be much of a problem other than having a little bit longer rowkeys. If it's a must to have that exact format, you'll have to implement your own job to read from MySQL and write to HBase with your custom serialization for either the row key or the column values.

Comment: The REPLACE function can replace characters. But how to convert a whole DATE variable to byte array? I still need the modified_date to be converted to byte array.

Comment: You can't, everything is imported as string: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1766141 "Sqoop currently serializes all values to HBase by converting each field to its string representation (as if you were importing to HDFS in text mode), and then inserts the UTF-8 bytes of this string in the target cell."

Comment: Just want to make sure you understand how to convert the date to byte array. We all know that in JAVA the Date can be converted to Long value, then it can be converted to 8 bytes to denote the Long value. I just want to append the 8 bytes to the row key. I understand SQOOP only supports string, but we can convert the 8 bytes to a string. Then pass the string presentation of the bytes to Sqoop. I just don't know how to convert date to long then to bytes then to string in SQL.

Comment: If SQL cannot do the conversion of Date -> Long -> Byte[] -> String, tell me how to implement my own job with custom serialization. Or give me a link to a tutorial or an example. Thanks.

Comment: You can `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_date)*1000` to format the date as a timestamp with milliseconds, the problem is that sqoop will convert it to it's string representation instead storing it as a 8 byte long (i.e.: `1423782000000=>"1423782000000" => 13B` instead of `\x00\x00\x01\x4B\x82\x3F\xAC\x90=> 8B` ). In theory, you could use a combination of mysql HEX() & UNHEX() functions to generate the an 8 byte UTF8 string from the number: `CAST(UNHEX(LPAD(HEX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_date)*1000),16,"0")) AS CHAR)` but mysql is going to have a lot of problems with `\x00`s so... I wouldn't do it.

Comment: To overcome this, you can create a small java program to scan the mysql table (easy task) and write to HBase in batches using any serialization you want (with the native java API). Here is a simple example of writing to HBase in batches: https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/ch03/src/main/java/client/PutListExample.java